# What am I doing wrong in solving the following matrix easy equation?

Tags: matrices

If $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\7&4\end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}-3&2\\5&-3\end{bmatrix}=I_2$$
Then I think A will be:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\7&4\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}-3&2\\5&-3\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}4&-7\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-3&-5\\-2&-3\end{bmatrix}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}-12+14&-20+21\\2-4&5+3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-1&8\end{bmatrix}$$
But this is wrong but I see no reason why, I also maintained order while multiplying inverses.

Comment: The first inverse is incorrect.

Comment: @GitGud why,don't you just exchange diagonals and negatize off diagonal elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\pmatrix{2&1\\7&4}^{-1} = \frac1{2\cdot 4-7\cdot1} \pmatrix{4&-1\\-7&2} = \pmatrix{4&-1\\-7&2}$$
and
$$\pmatrix{-3&2\\5&-3}^{-1} = \frac1{(-3)\cdot(-3) - 2\cdot 5} \pmatrix{-3&-2\\-5&-3} = -\pmatrix{-3&-2\\-5&-3} = \pmatrix{3&2\\5&3}$$
Thus
$$A = \pmatrix{7&5\\-11&-8}$$

Generally
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}^{-1} = \frac1{ad-bc} \pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}$$

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to show the step of dividing by the determinant, -1, for the second matrix, so the asker isn't confused?

Comment: @user_of_math Was editing while you commented :) Done now.

Answer (score 2):

You're calculating the inverse matrices incorrectly. The inverse of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is $\frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$.